# Как правильно настроить IdentityServer4 на работу с ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, identityserver4

Задача настроить IdentityServer4 на работу c ActiveDirectory. На данный момент реализована аутентификация через доменную систему, но непонятно как извлекать информацию о пользователе из домена.
Как получить структуру групп из ActiveDirectory и информацию о пользователях, чтобы в соответствии с ней распределять доступы к сервисам?